# javascript / PHP (NOT AJAX) - is there a way to cancel a post once it has been submitted and is in motion?

Tags: php, javascript, forms, post

javascript / PHP (NOT AJAX) - is there a way to cancel a post once it has been submitted and is in motion?

- So the user hits the post button - all is well and form is submitted PHP is ready to catch the details.
- For whatever reason there is network congestion and the server does not respond.
- I want to give the user a chance to post again after a time has passed.

**IS there a way to cancel the actual POST once it has been sent?**

**IS there a way to actually detect - on the server side - that a post was received?**

(In this case data is to be saved in the database)

I'm imagining the whole post procedure has a beginning and an end on the server side?

...

**Or - Is there a way to know for sure that the post is going no where. It has failed and that's the end of it?**

Comment: Well when you think the POST has not reached server, then why even cancel it in the first place? Simply add some JS to check if there is no response in x seconds then enable the submit button again

Comment: Just sneakily editing the question to add "NOT AJAX" without a comment is a bit sneaky :P.
I'm afraid I have to agree - the answer is no - you can't "Cancel" the post.  Perhaps you could explain exactly what you are trying to achieve, what the problem is etc, there might be another way around what you are doing?

Comment: Wrong... Not "sneaky" Just clarification - The post tile said "Javascript and PHP" it should be understood that I did not want an Ajax solution

Comment: so.. .you don't think it is possible that the post cold transmit and the server time out in the response stage Hank?

Comment: "exactly" trying to catch the cruddy godaddy server not responding... or any server for that matter. If in the event that some wild and absolutely crazy thing like a server time out or network glitch - how to be sure it has failed or timed out... etc. Instead of just guessing with a timer - and responding to an uncertainty

Comment: Not sure I'm satisfied here.
I do believe there is a way to follow the full and complete incipient and return post action. I'll research a bit more. Or maybe post again with the very clear (initial) statement of "NOT AJAX" So as not to "Make" anyone look any particular way.

Comment: Post must have some structure... Rather than at the time you PHP - or other - catches the post variables. Post must have some structure on its own.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't abort it. There is nothing you can do about it.

`IS there a way to actually detect - on the server side - that a post was received?`

Yes! Check the `$_POST` variable

Comment: The the post is sent, it is sent. Then the PHP script is executed. If the server times out or doesn't respond you should check what it's doing, since this sounds like a script which eats away the ressources

Comment: Just a crappy godaddy server that times out - it is a very basic post of a small form. Nothing crazy. Nothing to lag in any way.

Answer (score 0):

If you POST using AJAX then you can always re-post it.  Listen for the response, if a response hasn't been received within a certain amount of time, stop listening and re-post.  Otherwise you respond by changing the URL of the page using `document.location = "MyNextPage.php`

However you should be aware, there's no way to cancel the POST per se.  If it is going to get to the server it will still get there.  i.e. you could suffer from a double posting.  You should probably introduce a variable on the page, which is unique, so that a double posting can't occur.

===EDIT after the question parameters have changed===

If you have a unique parameter on the page, when you submit the post - you could also fire off a javascript timer to re-submit the after a chosen period.  If the page hasn't moved off by then (As the server hasn't responded) the javascript timer will fire, re-submitting the form. (You will want to check that this works in various browsers as the behaviour is largely undefined).

On the server just check if that unique value has already been submitted (Check the DB for this value, and write it in then continue if it's not already there).  Thus preventing double submission

Comment: I'm starting to like this idea.... Maybe a unique variable could work.... timeout... etc... But  I just figured there was a way to know exactly